# Is it possible to format strings using functions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-interpolation

I have a string containing an encoded password that I would like to decode. Is there a way to do this using string formatting (or any other method)?

For example:

```
decode_passwords = lambda password: password # plus some decoding logic..

string = "Password: {some_value}"
decoded_string = string.format(decode_passwords)
```

Comment: What would be the input to the lambda in this example? `some_value`?

Comment: Yes, with `some_value` being a string that is expected to change with different use cases.

Comment: No, there's nothing built in that does that (that I can think of).  You can get something somewhat similar using f-strings, but they're evaluated immediately, so you would lose the dynamism you're looking for.  `f = decode_passwords; "Password: {f('some_value')}"`